# Spring4D latest not compatible with DSharp?

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I downloaded Spring4D "sglienke-spring4d-ca8037a2fdec.zip" from this link https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/downloads/.

And I downloaded DSharp "sglienke-dsharp-2eae62962442.zip" from this link https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/dsharp/downloads/

I tried to build DSharp using Tokyo 10.2.3, and having the following errors - seems DSharp is not compatible with the latest Spring4D commit?

[dcc32 Error] DSharp.Collections.Iterators.pas(54): E2170 Cannot override a non-virtual method

[dcc32 Error] DSharp.Collections.Iterators.pas(66): E2170 Cannot override a non-virtual method

[dcc32 Error] DSharp.Collections.Iterators.pas(129): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'fState'

[dcc32 Error] DSharp.Collections.Iterators.pas(147): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'fState'

[dcc32 Error] DSharp.Collections.Iterators.pas(148): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'STATE_ENUMERATOR'

[dcc32 Error] DSharp.Collections.Iterators.pas(149): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'STATE_RUNNING'

[dcc32 Error] DSharp.Collections.Iterators.pas(149): E2030 Duplicate case label

[dcc32 Error] DSharp.Collections.Iterators.pas(156): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'fCurrent'

[dcc32 Error] DSharp.Collections.Iterators.pas(160): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'STATE_FINISHED'

[dcc32 Error] DSharp.Collections.Iterators.pas(173): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'fState'

[dcc32 Fatal Error] DSharp.Core.dpk(38): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'DSharp.Collections.Iterators.pas'

Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:00.8

Comment: Going by the comments on this post: https://plus.google.com/108264621339439827681/posts/V2GKUxh5vEb, I would not expect miracles.

Comment: ...but you could try logging an issue, here: https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/dsharp/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use develop branch of Spring4D if you need compatibility with DSharp but the latest released version.

Currently compatible are Spring4D 1.2.1 and the DSharp spring-1.2.1 branch.

Comment: Thank you.  DSharp is a great gem. Hope it is not discontinued. Or maybe it can be merged with Spring4D in some way.